# Issues with sending large email with Laravel job

Tags: php, laravel, queue, job-scheduling

This is my controller that get contact emails of over 50k and iterate over it then batched it to queue

[image: This is my controller that get contact emails of over 50k and iterate over it then batched it to queue]

This is the job that send the email

[image: This is the job that send the email]

The problem is that the email can only send to less than 500 contacts without any issue but anything above 1000 contact will result to maximum execution timeout

How can I solve this problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you show code of `BroadEmail` ? especial first portion?

Comment: That's the second image @saroj

Comment: could you send the first portion? I just want to check what you are importing, and which traits you are using?

Comment: Ok in a minute @Saroj

Comment: I just added the BroadEmail image @SarojShrestha

Comment: did you tried this `php artisan queue:listen --timeout=0` ?

Comment: --timeout=0? What does that implies? @SarojShrestha

Comment: It just allows as much time as it needed

Answer (score 0):

This statement is going to retrieve and store all your 50k in memory:

```php
$contacts = Contact::where(...)->where(...)->get();
```

I suggest [chunking the results](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#chunking-results) to avoid memory exhaustion.

Back to your problem, I am thinking about chunking the results (about 500 each) and dispatch an intermediary job that will eventually send emails.

```
class SendEmailsInChunk implements ShouldQueue
{
    public $contacts;
    public $batch;

    function __construct(public $batch, public $contacts) {}

    public function handle()
    {
        foreach ($this->contacts as $contact) {
            $this->batch->add(new BroadCampaignJob(..., $contact, ...));
        }
    }
```

Then you can chunk the results and dispatch the above job with each chunk:

```php
$batch = ...;

$query = Contact::where(...)->chunk(500, function ($contacts) use ($batch) {
    SendEmailsInChunk::dispatch($batch, $contacts);
})
```

Comment: Where would the last part that you dispatched the email be? Still under the foreach loop inside the job class handle? @kevin

Comment: I keep having this error following your process
Exception: Serialization of 'closure' is not allowed in file ...Queue.php on line 158

Comment: I keep having this error following your process Exception: Serialization of 'closure' is not allowed in file ...Queue.php on line 158.
@KevinBui